# Scaling of BLAS routines

Tags: matrix-multiplication, blas

A naive approach to calculate the action of a n x m matrix on a vector with m entries would lead to a code that scales like O(n x m).

I know that using the BLAS routines is a good choice for such calculations, but do they also scale better than O(n x m)? Or are they just faster than the naive approach but have the same scaling?

Answer (score 0):

Same scaling. Optimized BLAS usually faster. Sometimes same speed, as the naive for-loop may be optimized by a good compiler with correct compile options. This is the situation for BLAS level 2 operations such as matrix-vector multiplication.